# Проблема с nodejs, как быть?

Tags: node.js, npm

Обновил на машине (Ubuntu 14.04)  node до версии v4.0.0, и когда в консоли делаю запрос node -v, то все ок, версия v4.0.0, но вот когда nodejs -v в консоли, то показывает v0.10.40 версию, почему так? И как это исправить? Обновлял но ничего не вышло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo ln -s `which nodejs` /usr/bin/node
```

или

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove node
sudo apt-get --purge remove nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: я это проделал уже, и получил в итоге nodejs версии v0.10.40, и как ее теперь обновить до следующей версии? скажем v0.12

Comment: тут посмотрите: http://askubuntu.com/questions/235655/node-js-conflicts-sbin-node-vs-usr-bin-node/320271#320271
второй ответ в частности

Comment: ну и кардинальный ответ, конечно https://www.archlinux.org/ ) как ни странно, со временем rolling-releases - это вин

Answer (score 2):

Если машина с Ubuntu используется для разработки, то советую удалить установленную версию node и использовать [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). С помощью этой утилиты вы оперативно можете получать последнюю версию node. А в качестве бонуса ещё и оперативно переключаться между различными версиями node. И всё это без использования прав суперпользователя.

Для установки node 4.0 выполните `nvm install 4.0`